# Kendo NumericTextbox not showing correct decimal value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I'm defining a Kendo numeric textbox in my MVC 4 project as indicated below

```
 @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m.Rate)
                                     .Name("Rate")
                                     .Decimals(2)
                                     .Min(0)
                                     .Max(99999)
                                  )
```

The value as received from the model is 100, but is displayed as 10,000.00 by the Kendo NumericTextbox. When I save this model back to the database it is saved as 100. So it looks like it is only the display that is the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add culture js scripts on your page. Details are [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/overview).

Comment: Yes, thank you that worked. Included and initialized the culture script.